# Regional differences in Borderlands 2

Tags: ps3, borderlands-2, version-differences, region-lock

General question:  Are there any differences in Borderlands 2, based on the game's region code?

Specific case:  I received a game coded for Region 3, but I live in the U.S..  Are there any significant differences I should expect between this game and the game that is made for the U.S.?

I have been able to run the game, and everything appears to be in English so far.  So, I suppose my primary concern is about any content differences - is there anything that was censored for Region 3 or, to my benefit instead, anything that was unlocked for it as opposed to the U.S. version?

Comment: I was only following the news on the PC version (and that ugly story with Russian version), but I remember them saying they've gone some length to release uncut version globally. This is obvious from the lack of exploding heads and flesh-stripped skeletons, alas.

Comment: @OrcJMR aw is THAT why shock kills don't result in heads popping anymore?

Comment: @BenBrocka Yep... lack of watermelon-popping from criticals did upset me for some time. But Germans are probably getting more gore now than if the game got censored specifically for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the game itself may be the same as the one available on your region, you should know that DLC from the American PSN store will not work with your copy of the games. If you wish to download DLC for your game, you'll need to download it from the game region's store.

Comment: Good info to have.  Do you have a citation you could provide for this?

Comment: It's common knowledge that PS3 DLC is "region locked", i.e. you can only download DLC for a game on its regional store. I know this from personal experience but quick a Google search turns up few results: [this](http://whirlpool.net.au/wiki/ps3_regional_locking), for example, and [the wikipedia article on regional locking states that as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regional_lockout#Sony)

Answer (score 0):

Censorship is usually within a country and not within a region.
I live in germany (which is region 2) and and we have an awful lot of games that are rated age 18 and are heavily censored.
But if I buy the same game in the netherlands (same dvd region and borders to germany) it is completely uncut.

To answer your question: Check from where exactly you bought your game and then check wether or not it was censored in that particular country.